# codeigniter user_agent db retrieval

Tags: codeigniter, user-agent, php

I have a ci_session table in my database filled up.

Now when I want to retrieve the data from the database to see maybe which browsers visit my site most often I get the result that looks like this :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
```

Is there s away to make it display only the browser and version like this:

```
Chrome 32.0.1700.102
```

without messing around the library?

Comment: That's what browsers output. Feel free to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate User Agent Class. You can use something like this to set and store the Browser name and version in your session.

```
  // assuming that you have already started the session...
   public function setBrowserInSession(){

   if( $agent = $this->returnUserAgent() ) {

   $this->session->set_userdata('browser', $agent);}

   }


 public function returnUserAgent() {

    $this->load->library( 'user_agent' );

    $agent = ''; 

    // is it browser? if yes get browser name and version
    if ( $this->agent->is_browser() ) {
        $agent = $this->agent->browser().' '.$this->agent->version();}

            // robot? 
    elseif ( $this->agent->is_robot() ) {
        $agent = $this->agent->robot();}

            // mobile ? 
    elseif ( $this->agent->is_mobile() ) {
        $agent = $this->agent->mobile();}

    else { $agent = 'Unidentified User Agent'; }

    return $agent ; 
}
```

more info at: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html